# f#: Using a "match/with" block sans the "with"

Tags: f#

I am writing a function in f# that could be done with several if/else blocks but reads much cleaner with a match/with clause. The issue is that in many cases, I do not care about the variable actually being matched; I am using "when" everywhere instead.

The question is, is there a way of doing a "match/with" using only "when" blocks and no actual match variable?

```
let primes (input:bigint) = 
    let rec factors acc (input':bigint, factor:bigint) = 
        match input' with
        | _ when input' = 1I -> acc
        | _ when input = factor -> factor::acc
        | _ when input' = factor -> factor::acc
        | _ when input' % factor = 0I -> factor::factors acc (input'/factor, factor)
        | _ -> factors acc (input', factor+1I)
    in factors [] (input, 2I)

primes 1I |> List.iter (printf "%A "); printfn "..";    
primes 12I |> List.iter (printf "%A "); printfn "..";
primes 60I |> List.iter (printf "%A "); printfn "..";
primes 420I |> List.iter (printf "%A "); printfn "..";
primes 1260I |> List.iter (printf "%A "); printfn "..";
primes 13I |> List.iter (printf "%A "); printfn "..";
```

---

[Edit] It has been suggested that this is the same question as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31877649/f-multi-condition-if-else-versus-matching) and I suppose it is. But if not for this post, I would not have seen Carsten's answer, which is what I thought I was looking for. Now that I know it, I guess the two alternatives are as follows

```
let primes (input:bigint) = 
    let rec factors acc (input':bigint, factor:bigint) = 
        match () with
        | () when input' = 1I           -> acc
        | () when input = factor        -> factor::acc
        | () when input' = factor       -> factor::acc
        | () when input' % factor = 0I  -> factor::factors acc (input'/factor, factor)
        | _ -> factors acc (input', factor+1I)
    in factors [] (input, 2I)

let primes' (input:bigint) = 
    let rec factors acc (input':bigint, factor:bigint) = 
        if   input' = 1I            then acc
        elif input = factor         then factor::acc
        elif input' = factor        then factor::acc
        elif input' % factor = 0I   then factor::factors acc (input'/factor, factor)
        else factors acc (input', factor+1I)
    in factors [] (input, 2I)
```

Seeing them side by side like this leaves me with the opinion that I should use the elif's.

Comment: possible duplicate of [F# multi-condition if/else versus matching](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31877649/f-multi-condition-if-else-versus-matching)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you could use active-patterns, but I think it's too much overhead in this case here - if not you cannot really escape the `where` here (or at least I am not *aware* of any way).

There is a *pattern* that will make this a bit more obvious (that you don't care about the value matched only about the `when` clauses):

```
match () with 
| () when ... -> ... 
| () when ... -> ...
| _ -> ...
```

you might have seen.

Answer (score 2):

The conditions supplied here relate to different inputs, so there's not much to match on. These are the situation where `if/else` chains are more concise. You can, however, use the slightly short `elif` keyword:

```
let primes (input:bigint) = 
    let rec factors acc (input':bigint, factor:bigint) =
        if input' = 1I then acc
        elif input = factor then factor::acc
        elif input' = factor then factor::acc
        elif input' % factor = 0I then factor::factors acc (input'/factor, factor)
        else factors acc (input', factor+1I)
    in factors [] (input, 2I)
```

Pattern matching is valuable when you have a *single* input that can have various different flavours or shapes, but in this case, you rather have various different inputs, where the relationship between those determine the branching, in a hierarchical fashion.